# Where to install Node.js and other such programs/tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, web-development-server

I have two computers.

Computer 1 is a Windows 7 computer. It is my main computer where I use it for web browsing, gaming, paying bills, etc..  I also use it for all of my development work. I am currently using Visual Studio Code and to a lesser extent Visual Studio 2015 Professional.  My main focus at this time is Javascript, PHP, HTML, CSS.

Computer 2 is Linux Ubuntu that i have configured as a web-server.  I used the tutorials from Digital Ocean to create the web-server.

I currently own two domains purchased through google domains and I have two simple websites that I am currently hosting on this web-server.  The websites were built using a combination of PHP, Javascript/JQuery, HTML and CSS.

I wish to expand my knowledge base so I have recently started looking at Node.js and will also be looking at Angular.js and other .js's.

I installed Node.js on Computer 1, my 'daily/development' computer.  My question is do I need to install it on my WebServer?  I wrote a small Node.js web app on my development computer and moved it to my server and it worked but I am not sure if this would work for something bigger.  I know I could just write something and experiment but I was hoping to get some advice from others who have a similar setup before I go down a frustrating path.

In general, if you have an 'everyday/development' computer and a separate dedicated web-server, how do you know where to install things like Node.js, Angular.js, etc... I have viewed numerous tutorials on You Tube and Plural Sight about these tools/languages/frameworks but the vast majority of them do not seem to address equipment issues, which I guess makes sense.  I know there is a Plural Sight course that is actually dedicated to set up a development environment and I tried to follow it but it was a little too advanced for me.

Thanks in advance for the guidance!

Comment: Client side code goes on your windows machine, server side code goes on your Linux machine :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. Install them on the machine you are more comfortable for you.

> In general, if you have an 'everyday/development' computer and a separate dedicated web-server, how do you know where to install things like Node.js, Angular.js, etc...

If you want to learn and test stuff it doesn't really matter on what computer you are going to install them. For example I have a RaspberryPi ubuntu server which is online 24/7. I write my code/apps on my development machine (which I use only when I'm coding/playing games/doing work) and then migrate/move the code and run it on the linux server. (You can see what git/bitbucket is).

And don't worry to make the wrong decision with your setup - you will learn a lot like that. By the way there is no right or wrong answer here.

Comment: Hi Combine, thanks very much for the feedback.  It gets a little overwhelming at times so it is nice to hear from other people what they do.  Your feedback has taken off the 'pressure' off needing to get it right the first time!

Comment: No problem mate. Happy coding!